# How does the Climb skill work with a double move action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [Climb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/climb) skill states "With a successful Climb check, you can advance up, down, or across a slope, wall, or other steep incline (or even across a ceiling, provided it has handholds) at one-quarter your normal speed."

The skill also states "Climbing is part of movement, so it’s generally part of a move action (and may be combined with other types of movement in a move action). Each move action that includes any climbing requires a separate Climb check."

Which makes it sound like if the character with 30 ft speed wanted to climb up a 10 ft wall they would need 1 move action with a Climb check to get 5 ft up and then a second move action with a new Climb check to get the other 5 ft up.

Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Or you can use [accelerated climbing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/climb), which allows you to move half your speed for a -5 penalty, which would let you get up there in one move action at some additional risk.